# What is the difference between malai paneer and paneer?

Tags: paneer

What is the difference between paneer and malai paneer? My wife asked me to buy paneer. In the shop I saw malai paneer and bought it. Are they the same?

Answer (score 3):

Raghavan Iyer's book, *660 Curries* has recipes for both Whole-milk cheese (doodh paneer) and creamy homemade cheese (malai paneer).  The only difference between teh two recipes is that the Malai paneer uses half-and-half while the doodh paneer uses whole milk.

Answer (score 0):

Paneer is a form of cheese, often resemblant of cottage cheese in Europe/US.

There are many recipies involving paneer, e.g. palak paneer and mattak paneer.

I believe malai to be a dairy product (heated milk high in fat). Malai paneer should be a type of paneer that is based on malai. My guess is that this is cream cheese.